# Updating column in for loop using merge

Tags: python, sql, pandas, numpy, merge

Hi,

I have two dataframes and I want to loop through subsets of my first DF and merge values to my second DF.

My data looks like:

```
 DF1 

 product      survey_id
  X1           survey_1
  x2           survey_1
  x3           survey_2
  x4           survey_3
  x5           survey_3
  x1           survey_3
  :             : 
  x(i)         survey(j)
```

My second DF contains the same products (only appear once/unique in DF2) and I have added an empty column to put the survey number in.

```
DF2

product      survey_id
 x1            nan
 x2            nan
  :             :
  :             : 
 x(i)          nan
```

What I want to do is take a subset of DF1 for each survey and merge them to DF2 so that should a product appear more than once, the most recent survey_id will appear in the survey_id column:

```
surveys = DF1['survey_id'].unique()

for survey in surveys:
    DF2 = DF2.merge(DF1['survey_id'] == survey], how='left', on='product')
```

If I sort the survey list I will be able to merge the survey data on in chronological order. From there I want to merge/fill the survey_id column with each iteration, overwriting the survey_id value should the product appear more than once.

I was hoping to take a subset of DF1 where, for example

```
  DF1[DF1['survey_id']=='survey_1']
```

and merge all this data to DF2. So where ever x(i) in DF1 and DF2 match we have

```
  DF2['survey_id'] = 'survey_1'
```

The next iteration of this loop will use a subset where

```
  DF1[DF1['survey_id']=='survey_2']
```

and the survey_id values will be set to 'survey_2' where the products match. The survey_id should be overwritten or filled if it is still NaN

EDIT:

```
output 

product      survey_id
  X1           survey_3
  x2           survey_1
  x3           survey_2
  x4           survey_3
  x5           survey_3
```

Not sure if merge is the best way to go about this. I was trying to use .loc but this doesn't seem to work either:

```
 DF2['survey_id'] = DF1['survey_id'].loc[DF1['product'] == DF2['substance']]
```

Comment: for all product xi, we require survey_j such that j is maximum. Is this what you want?

Answer (score 0):

This is based on assumption:

**for all product xi, we require survey_j such that j is maximum.**

```
>>> data = {'product':['x1','x1','x2','x2','x2'], 'survey_id':['survey_1','survey_2','survey_1', 'survey_2', 'survey_3'] } 
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data)
>>> df
  product survey_id
0      x1  survey_1
1      x1  survey_2
2      x2  survey_1
3      x2  survey_2
4      x2  survey_3
>>> df.groupby(['product'],as_index=False)['survey_id'].max()
  product survey_id
0      x1  survey_2
1      x2  survey_3
```

Comment: Not exactly what I'm looking for. I was hoping to take a subset of DF1 where, for example DF1[DF1['survey_id']=='survey_1'] and merge all this data to DF2. So where ever x(i) in DF1 and DF2 match we have DF2['survey_id'] = 'survey_1'.

Comment: The next iteration of this loop will use a subset where DF1[DF1['survey_id']=='survey_2'] and the survey_id values will be set to 'survey_2' where the products match. The survey_id should be overwritten or filled if it is still NaN

Comment: Can you tell what would be the output in the example I have used. Please provide examples in your question so that it will be more clear. I think what you are trying to achieve is similar to what my approach would offer.

Comment: Yes the output would be the same as yours but I would prefer to use a loop, I will add an example of the output

Comment: We should try reducing loops wherever possible and make use of pandas library functions. Pandas is based on numpy which is highly optimized for such tasks.

Comment: I have something like this now: DF1.loc[modeldb['product'].isin(DF2['product']), ['survey_id']] = DF2[['survey_id']]

Answer (score 0):

I hope this works. The idea is that having DF1, you could create a data frame (keys) with just the last survey ids and based on that populate DF2.

```
dict1 = {'product':['x1','x2','x3','x4','x5', 'x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'x4', 'x5'],
            'survey_id':['survey_1','survey_1','survey_2', 'survey_3', 'survey_3',
            'survey_3', 'survey_4', 'survey_4', 'survey_5', 'survey_5'] }

DF1 = pd.DataFrame(dict1)

keys = DF1.drop_duplicates('product',keep = "last")

dict2 = {'product':['x1','x2','x3','x4','x5']}

DF2 = pd.DataFrame(dict2)
DF2['survey_id'] = "nan"
DF2.head()

DF2 = pd.merge(keys, DF2, how = "left")
```

This should produce DF2 as follows:

```
product survey_id
0   x1  survey_3
1   x2  survey_4
2   x3  survey_4
3   x4  survey_5
4   x5  survey_5
```

Or simply:

```
DF2 = DF1.drop_duplicates('product','last').sort_values('product').reset_index(drop=True)
```